# how to fetch year on year data based on rule

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with id and date I need two outputs as below. I will pass an input date and I need records according to below conditions

output 1: I need less than or equal date data either it is month end or not for the first row and first-row date-1 year month end data and first-row date-2 year month end data and if data is not available for the particular year then return null on that row.

output 2: Same as first but with a twist that I need whatever data is available on first row date-1 and -2 I do not need null.

```
  declare @tbl table (id int , marketdate date )

     insert into @tbl (id,marketdate)
       values (1,'2018-05-31'),
              (1,'2017-05-29'),
              (1,'2016-05-31'),
              (2,'2018-02-28'),
              (2,'2017-02-28'), 
              (2,'2016-02-29'),
              (2,'2016-02-28')
```

My query :

```
        ;with cte as ( 

        select id , marketdate  
        from ( 
        select   id , marketdate   ,row_number() over(partition by id order by marketdate desc) rn 
        from @tbl
        where marketdate <='2018-06-05'
        ) a where rn=1 

        union all
        select id , marketdate  
        from ( 
        select b.id , b.marketdate ,row_number() over(partition by b.id order by b.marketdate desc) rn 
        from @tbl b inner join cte c 
        on b.id= c.id 
        where b.marketdate<= dateadd(year,-1,c.marketdate ) 
        ) b where rn=1  
        ) 
        select * from cte 
        order by id, marketdate desc
```

output 1:

```
 1   2018-05-31
 1   NUll 
 1   2016-05-31
 2   2018-02-28
 2   2017-02-28
 2   2016-02-29
```

output 2:

```
1   2018-05-31
 1   2017-05-29 
 1   2016-05-31
 2   2018-02-28
 2   2017-02-28
 2   2016-02-29
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you share what you've actually tried so far? I wouldn't expect someone to just write the entire query for you. Usually, it's proper form to provide your steps so far.

Comment: @pimbrouwers i added my query in question now. I tried using it with recursion but it fails.

Comment: I'm sorry but I couldn't understand the rules for the desired output. Can you please  [edit] your question to include some sample input and the output it should produce?